# mod_rewrite after a cname

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, cname-record

I have the domain foo.bar.example.com. foo is one of many sub-subdomains under bar.example.com. I need to capture and redirect all links at foo.bar.example.com that begin with "/special/".

- foo.bar.example.com/asdf <- should not redirect
- foo.bar.example.com/special/asdf <- should redirect
- otherfoo.bar.example.com/special/asdf <- should redirect

I have used the following code in my .htaccess to redirect foo.bar.example.com/special/asdf to special.example.com/foo/asdf successfully.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*?)\.bar\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^/special/(.*)$ http://special.example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

Awesome, everything works. What's the problem?

I have many partners (this.that.com, silly.billy.com, etc) that have set up cname's to point to my matching sub-subdomains (that.bar.example.com, billy.bar.example.com, etc). I need this.that.com/special/asdf to also redirect to special.example.com/that/asdf without the partner neededing to do any additional changes.

Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to test this at this time. From what I understand mod_rewrite works based on what is entered by the browser not what it gets cname'd to. If thats true, then will I will not be able to make use of my domain naming standard? I cannot rely on my partners to follow a similar standard. How can I get this.that.com/special/asdf to redirect to special.example.com/that/asdf?

Comment: Is the RewriteCond required? If you remove that it should work as you desire.

Comment: The rewrite condition is to grab the partners sub-subdomain for use in the rewrite. **foo**.bar.example.com/special/asdf to special.example.com/ **foo** /asdf I am unaware of another way to achive this.